# Vector space of convergent sequences, prove it's complete

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In the space of convergent sequences, such that for a convergent sequence $(a_n)$ we have $\sum _{n=1} ^{+ \infty} a_n ^2 < \infty$, we define a norm $(a_n) \rightarrow \sqrt{\sum _{n=1} ^{+ \infty} a_n ^2}$.

Prove that the space is complete with this norm and determine absolute and commutative convergence of $\sum _{n=1} ^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n} e_n$ in this space.

I've already checked that it is indeed a norm. Could you give me some help with the rest?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to show Cauchy sequence converges, what is a Cauchy sequence in this space? is bolzano-weirestrass useful here?

Comment: I think that a Cauchy sequence here is a sequence which terms are convergent sequences and  for every positive real number $\epsilon > 0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that for all natural numbers $m, n > N$ we have $||a_n-a_m|| = \sqrt{a_{n1} ^2 + a_{n2} ^2 + ... - a_{m1} ^2 - a_{m2} ^2 -...} $.

Comment: you made typos, check them again.

Comment: no, that is still wrong and it is not a typo.

Comment: $(x_n:n\in\Bbb N)$ is a Cauchy sequence here, where $x_n=( x_n(k):k\in\Bbb N)$

Comment: I'm sorry. I've edited my question. Is it ok now?

Comment: Could you help me find a sequence to which $(x_n:n\in\Bbb N)$ would converge?

Comment: Remark: this space is called $\ell^2$. More generallt $\ell^p$ is complete for all $p\geq 1$. These are fundamental Banach spaces. To prove completeness, it goes the same for each of them. Take a Cauchy sequence. Find a pointwise limite by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. Check the pointwise limit is in the space. Check convergence in the space.

Answer (score 1):

Your definiton of convergence is wrong

$||a_n-a_m||= \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_n(i)-a_m(i))^2}$

Now for each $i$, $a_n(i)$ must be a bounded sequence. (why?) what does bolzano-weirestrass tell you, which you can use to construct a candidate limit?